# Exception handler ter retorno em JSON

Tags: laravel, rest, exceção, lumen, handler

Estou construindo uma *RestAPI* usando *Laravel/Lumen*, em testes pode ocorrer do retorno ser totalmente em HTML, isso ocorre quando aparece aquela já famosa tela: *Whoops looks like something went wrong*

Isso atrapalha bastante testar a rest, e nunca pode acontecer no ambiente de produção, como eu posso fazer esse retorno ser em Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta alterar o *handler* de exceção do *framework*, localizado em `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`, alterando o método que faz a renderização das exceções, deixando-o assim:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $json = [
        'success' => false,
        'error' => [
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ],
    ];

    return response()->json($json, 400);
}
```

Basicamente sempre que ocorrer uma exceção você está pegando alguns dados, como o código o erro e a mensagem dele e retornando em *JSON*. No ambiente de produção isso nunca iria aparecer, desde que desabilite o `debug`.

Mas note que isso irá barrar também um `request` com validação errada, e você não será autorizado a pegar as mensagens de validação, para burlar isso precisamos responder em json nesse caso apenas quando o código do erro é diferente de zero, pois o erro zero é referente ao erro de validação, então o código ficará assim:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e->getCode() != 0) {
        $json = [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => [
                'code' => $e->getCode(),
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ],
        ];

        return response()->json($json, 400);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```